# Handle both Type cast and Condition for Default in Derived Column

Tags: ssis

I have created an SSIS package where two columns of type varchar(1) have to be mapped to columns of Integer.  I have this working using a Derived Column and giving both fields a type cast of (DT_I4).  However, I discovered in the complete data set there are records with no value in these two fields and so I have to Type Cast AND add a condition in expression to default to "0" if null.

So far I have tried the following but are not valid

```
(IsNull[Notes Taken])?(DT_I4)"0":[Notes Taken]
(DT_I4)(IsNull[Notes Taken])?"0":[Notes Taken]
```

How do I create this expression properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most simple solution is to use `REPLACENULL` function like:

```
REPLACENULL([Notes Taken], "0")
```

And then - cast it to `DT_I4`. This function replaces the logic you are devising with conditional operator.
Your both formulas have errors. The most prominent - `ISNULL` is a function and needs parenthesis around its arguments, `ISNULL([Notes Taken])`, brackets only define a dataflow column. See [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/functions-ssis-expression?view=sql-server-ver15).
Then, your first expression

```
(IsNull[Notes Taken])?(DT_I4)"0":[Notes Taken]
```

Possibly the field `[Notes Taken]` is not matching data type of the `DT_I4` which is the datatype of the first argument of `? :` operator.
Your second expression

```
(DT_I4)(IsNull[Notes Taken])?"0":[Notes Taken]
```

Applies the data cast to the logical function `ISNULL`, not to the complete expression. You should put the parenthesis around the complete `? :` operator like:

```
(DT_I4)(IsNull([Notes Taken])?"0":[Notes Taken])
```